# How is it possible check all the squares from nested list and print their indexes like coordinates?

Tags: python, list, nested, enumerate

The print method should read: "From square 'x', 'y' we find 'animal'". I must use enumerate -method to get the coordinates of the letters that represent animals and I'm struggling. The check-field method should call check_square method on every iteration.

```
ANIMALS = {
    "a": "alpaca",
    "k": "kangaroo",
    "@": "cat",
    "h": "hamster",
    "l": "leopard"
}


def check_square(char, row_num, col_num):

    if char != " ":    
        print("From square ({}, {}) we find {}"
        .format(col_num, row_num, ANIMALS[char]))



def check_field(field):

    for i in enumerate(field):
        #print(i)
        for j in enumerate(i):
            #print(i)
            #print(enumerate(field))
            #print(i)
            #print(j)
            check_square(field[i], enumerate(j), enumerate(i))


field = [
    [" ", "a", " ", " ", "l"],
    [" ", "k", "@", "k", " "],
    ["h", " ", "a", "k", " "]
]

check_field(field)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `check_field` function to:

```
def check_field(field):
    for y, row in enumerate(field):
        for x, char in enumerate(row):
            check_square(char, y, x)
```

The way yours is written, `i` and `j` are tuples. You are incorrectly iterating over `i` in the second for loop. You are also passing enumerate objects to `check_square` when you should be passing the indices/coordinates themselves.

You'll also want to edit your `check_square` function, specifically the string-formatting:

```
.format(col_num, row_num, ANIMALS[char])
```

Should become:

```
.format(col_num, row_num, ANIMALS.get(char, "nothing"))
```

Your `ANIMALS` dictionary doesn't have a key-value pair for `" "`. Trying to  access that key will raise a `KeyError`. Using the `.get` method allows you to provide a default in case a key is not present. Alternatively, you could also just have added an entry for `" "` in `ANIMALS`.